# Pass Angular (9) @Input() variable further up in two nested component

Tags: angular

I have 3 different components:

- `create-component`
- `form-a-component`
- `dropdown-status-component`

I would like to pass an enum value from the `create-component` to the `form-a-component` further up to the `dropdown-status-component`. Can I somehow just pass the `@Input()` variable further up instead of first assigning it to a component variable and then passing it on?
*Note: There will be more forms in the future like form-b, form-c and also an edit-component which would pass a different enum-value to the dropwdown-status-component.*

**create-component:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `<app-form-a [selectedState]="selectedState"></app-form-a>`,
})
export class CreateComponent {
   public selectedState: string = SelectedState[SelectedState.InProcess];
}
```

**form-a-component:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-form-a',
   template: `<dropdown-status [selectedState]="selectedState"></dropdown-status>`,
})
export class FormAComponent {
     @Input() public selectedState: string;
}
```

**dopdown-status-component:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-form-a',
   template: `<select formControlName="dropdownState"><option>...</select>`,
})
export class FormAComponent {
   @Input() public selectedState: string;
   this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          dropdownState: [{value: SelectedState}],
   });

   this.formGroup.controls['dropdownState'].setValue(this.selectedState, {onlySelf: true});
}
```

My current handling (form-a-component):

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-form-a',
   template: `<dropdown-status [selectedState]="setSelectedState"></dropdown-status>`,
})
export class FormAComponent {
   @Input() selectedState: string = "";
   public setSelectedState: string = this.selectedState;
}
```

Comment: `@Input` can pass the data only to immediate siblings. To share data to unrelated components, you could use singleton services.

Comment: Can you confirm that what you want to do is pass the value _directly_ from the `create-a-component` to the `dropdown-status-component`? Your current wording isn't fully clear.

Comment: I would use a service here that all the components that need to see the variable have access to.